# How to manage multiple views in .storyboard or .xib file via coding.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am new to iphone, i have sucessfully implemented .xib file in my main.storyboard file (Fig-1) but unable to import same .xib file on next view of same .storyboard file (fig-2 other views in same .storyboard file). Please suggest me how to import same .xib file on other view also.[image: fig-1 main.storyboard file withi imported .xib file]

[image: Figure two showing other view of same .storyboard file]

ViewController.m   (Affecting main.storyboard)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CustomView *customView = [CustomView customView];
    [self.view addSubview:customView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your next view page of .storyboard, click on
 Identity inspector -> class -> ViewController

It will reflect the common xib file in your next view of your same .storyboard file

Answer (score 1):

In the viewdidload of nextView controller add these lines -

```
UIView *customView= [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
                             [_containerView addSubview:customView];
```

Comment: sir, i have to create seprate .h .m file for other view or we will just have to refrence it under Viewcontroller.m.

Comment: ViewController.m   (Affecting main.storyboard)